# Selecting data from two tables. What's wrong with this sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join

I'm collecting informations from two tables.

My command:

```
select p.prod_id, p.prod_fornecedor, p.prod_fabricante, p.prod_nome, p.prod_categoria, p.prod_datacadastro,
       p.prod_codbarras, e.est_quantidade from Produto p join Estoque e on p.prod_nome like 'Produto 1'
```

What I'm getting:
[image]
I need to get this:
[image]

Comment: you are just doing the join on p.prod_nome and no link between Produto and Estoque. Maybe you should do join on p.prod_nome = e.prod_nome (or maybe prod_id in both tables?) and where prod_nome like 'Produto 1'. Just what I m guessing, show us the table definitions and some sample data and we will help you for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a join condition in the query. Assuming table `Estoque` has a field `prod_id`:

```
select 
    p.prod_id, p.prod_fornecedor, p.prod_fabricante, 
    p.prod_nome, p.prod_categoria, p.prod_datacadastro,
    p.prod_codbarras, e.est_quantidade 
from Produto p 
join Estoque e on p.prod_id = e.prod_id
where p.prod_nome like 'Produto 1'
```